# .apk file not working on device

Tags: android

i took an android project and imported it in eclipse. in properties->android section it is showing platform 1.6 and API level 4. I have downloaded Android 2.2. Now when i try to make some changes in the source code and make an .apk file and try to install on my android device the device shows an error : Application not installed. the project is not showing any error but it is showing a warning : Attribute minSdkVersion (3) is lower than the project target API level (4) in manifest file. the person who gave me th eproject i asked him to mail his .apk file to me and that .apk file is running perfectly on the device. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Change to API level 3 (Android 1.5), that must be the solution. you must have in your manifest.xml defined a minSdkVersion = 3

```
    </application>    

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

or change the  minSdkVersion to Api level 4  at your manifest.xml file that correspond to android 1.6

```
    </application>    

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

build, create and sign your .apk again

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could try this:
when application run on emulator it creates an .apk file on project/bin folder. you just connect your android phone with usb mass storage and then copy this apk to SD card. it will then install the app on phone by clicking the apk file on phone. i've faced the same problem and now i've successfully installed my apps on t mobile G1.